# Deploy ES6 modules base express JS app to vercel

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

I have created a Git repository for an Express.js project and I'm using ES6 Modules instead of CommonJS modules. When I deploy my application to Vercel, I encounter a runtime error with the following message:

{"errorType":"ReferenceError","errorMessage":"require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead\nThis file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.","stack":["ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead","This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension."," at file:///var/task/___now_launcher.js:1:18"}

Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue? I want to continue using ES6 Modules in my Express.js project on Vercel. What steps should I take to fix this error and ensure that my project functions correctly?

Thank you for your assistance!